# Dynamic Arrays and structs

Tags: c, c99

Thanks! I just had to cast the right side of the assignment to Term.

I have to make a dynamic array of polynomials that each have a dynamic array of terms.  When giving the term a exponent and coefficient, I get an error "expected expression before '{' token".  What am I doing incorrectly when assigning the values?

Also, is there an easy way of keeping the dynamic array of terms ordered by their exponent?  I was just planning on looping through, printing the max value but would prefer to store them in order.

Thanks!

```
polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm[0] = {exponent, coefficient};  // ISSUE HERE
```

change to

```
polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm[0] = (Term){exponent, coefficient};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is C99, I think you need

```
polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm[0] = (Term){exponent, coefficient};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm[0]->exponent = exponent;
polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm[0]->coefficient = coefficient;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an efficiency problem here in your code:

```
  if(index > (sizeof(polynomialArray)/sizeof(Polynomial)))
      polynomialArray = (Polynomial*)realloc(polynomialArray, index * sizeof(Polynomial));
```

as *polynomialArray* is a pointer, I think **sizeof(polynomialArray)** would always be 4 or 8(64-bit system). So the above **if** statement will always true as long as *index* is greater than 0.

Comment: Good catch. `sizeof(X)` gives the answer the original author intended if and only if `X` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attribute values like that (only during declaration).

You should assign like this:

```
polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm[0].exponent = exponent;
polynomialArray[index].polynomialTerm[0].coefficient = coefficient;
```

About the other question, you really don't need assert here. The pointer will not be NULL if it has a value malloc allocated to it. If not, it is better to be NULL, so you can test if malloc failed.

To have it ordered, you will need to order using some sort algorithm. I think that if you are looking for an easy way, the way you are doing is fine. If it is critical to be ordered (like real time applications), than you need to rethink the approach. If not, keep it and go forward!

Take care,
Beco